# How to create chained list view in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, parse-platform

I'm trying to build a study app for android which allows the users to reference source code for different computer programs.
First of all the user gets presented with a list of subjects from which he has to choose from. Next he will be provided with list of programs from that subject. And finally when he will select an experiment, he'll be provided with the source code of the program. 
I want to provide the layout for selecting the subject list and the list of programs as a list view and for providing the source code of the program as text view. 
Also I want to implement this using MVC framework such that I can update the content of the app from backend using parse and thus the user doesn't require to update the app for getting new content.

How should I proceed for the same?